# htaccess redirect only specific page, not subpages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server

I have a website with following url structure:

- `www.example.com/products`
- `www.example.com/products/productA`
- `www.example.com/products/productB`

I need to redirect `www.example.com/products` to `www.example.com` but `www.example.com/products/productA` and `productB` should still be available.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^products$ / [R=302,L]
```

I've used mod_rewrite here, as opposed to a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive since I assume you are already using mod_rewrite later in the file to rewrite your URLs. It is preferable not to mix redirects/rewrites from both modules.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule